# Spring Tool Suite 4.1.1.RELEASE can not create schema.sql in resources

Tags: development

While working through chapter 5 of "Pro Spring Boot 2" I Used http://start.spring.io to generate a spring boot project:
Group: com.apress.todo
Artifact: todo-jdbc
Name: todo-jdbc
Package Name: com.apress.todo
Dependencies: Web, Lombok, JDBC, H2, MySQL

I then unzipped the todo.zip to a folder and imported it into the Spring Tool Suite (STS) as an existing maven project.

When I try to create a schema.sql file (or any *.sql file) in src/main/resources I see an error window stating "Application not found" and after clicking Ok the file appears in the folder tree.  However, if I try to open the file, the error appears again and the file will not open.

If I attempt to create test.txt in src/main/resources no errors occur and the file opens as expected.

It seems to me that STS is preventing creation of sql resource files for some reason - but the error message is very misleading.

Has anyone encountered similar errors with STS 4.1.1 ?  If so, how did you resolve it ?

(In case it matters I am using Windows 10 Pro 64)

Answer (score -1):

This behavior appears to be a bug in the Sprint Tool Suite.
The workaround is this:
1. Exit the tool suite after the error message and the sql file has been created.
2. Using your favourite text editor, insert the sql statements your application requires and save the modified file
3. Restart the tool suite and run your application

The application will now read and process the sql file as expected.

Does anyone know how to report this bug to the Sprint Tool Suite developers ?

Comment: Don't ask questions in answers please. We're glad you learned this was a bug, but questions don't belong in answers. Also, a quick Google brings up the Spring.io site which includes pretty clear places to contact the devs. So Google, as usual, is the best place to start your search.

Comment: You must think that I am a neophyte.  I challenge you to send me the URL from the spring.io website that tells me how to report a bug.

Comment: Hold on to your horses. First a Google search quickly finds spring.io as the source site, which includes a list of all of the developers on the team including links to their various social media profiles. Second, that site ALSO links to the publisher, Pivotal, which has a Contact Us link on their page. Third (and it's third because I'm not seeing it on mobile but I know I saw it yesterday on desktop) there is a link on one of these pages to their Github, which is as much a feedback tool as it is a code repository. So, cool your jets and don't ask questions in your answers.

Comment: A quick Google does confirm Spring.io has a github.

Comment: Thanks for answering  the question I asked in my answer.  Like you I had already found the github using Google and reported the bug. You couldn't find the URL on spring.io because it isn't there.  This was fun, eh ?

Comment: We appear to have rather different views of fun. You are correct in that there is no large flashing sign featured prominently on every page of the Spring.io site linking to Github. However, in the Blog there are several places where the Github is linked, and every single profile on the Team page includes their Github link. I would agree that a friendly and prominent Help button or interaction piece would be a good idea for any published product, but they didn't exactly hide their help from people with technical experience.